# One command, 2 possible command targets

Tags: c#, wpf, command

Following situation: I've got 2 ListBoxes, each one containing a separate list of removeable elements.

If I'm now going to add a Delete Command (which is working fine for ContextMenu as I get the selected Element as OriginalSource), I have the problem that I can't distinguish which ListBox is meant (since the OriginalSource is the Window).

Using the FocusManager doesn't work (always returns null) even though the GotFocus event is triggered for the listBoxes.

A simple solution would be to store the selected ListBox in the GotFocus event, but I'm looking for a more generic, scalable solution (so I get all the information from the arguments provided to the CanExecute/Execute methods of the Command)

Comment: By default `CommandTarget` will be focused element and then it will go up the visual tree to find some `CommandBinding`. Each of your `Listbox` can have different `CommandBinding`

Comment: What you can do is create two buttons one for each listbox. Then using the `CommandParameter` you can distinguish which listbox sent the delete `Command`.

Answer (score 0):

You could offer a LastSelectedItem property on your viewmodel. Allways set this property when you set one of the SelectedItems from the listboxes. Then search your two lists for the item and remove it.

Comment: There is a small flaw with this approach. After selecting an item from listbox instead of the clicking the delete button command if the user clicks some where else on the window and then clicks the delete button the item would be deleted. the button should only be enabled after the user selects an item and then clicks the delete button. For any other case the button should be disabled.

Comment: Or put the button inside the ItemTemplate of the ListBox. This way there would be no doubt, which Item should be deleted.